# Jamod, детектировать изменение processImage \ детектировать наличие обмена

Tags: java, modbus

Создан Slave TCP Modbus при помощи библиотеки Jamod (пробовал так же j2mod с тем же результатом) согласно документации. Работает, обмен идет, но есть пара вопросов:

1.Как правильно повесить слушателя на изменение регистров? Необходимо проводить некоторые действия когда значения регистров изменились. Сейчас периодически итерирую регистры в поисках измененных, но такое решение крайне не нравится.

2.Можно ли штатными возможностями jamod отследить наличие обмена между slave и master?

Comment: несвязанные вопросы надо задавать отдельно.

Comment: Ну на русскоязычном stackoverflow как ни задай вопрос, ответа вряд ли дождешься :)